# using clone(): segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, clone

I want to use clone to log the current status of my program.
It has a lot of loops and I want to keep track of the process without printing the status in each loop iteration.

That's why I created this proof-of-concept:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

unsigned int i;

int log(void*) {
  std::cout << "LOGGING START" << std::endl;
  while(true) {
    sleep(1);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()  {
  void **child_stack = (void**)malloc(16384);
  i = 0;

  std::clog << "calling clone" << std::endl;
  clone(log, child_stack, CLONE_VM | CLONE_FILES, NULL);
  std::clog << "done" << std::endl;

  while(true) {
    ++i;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When I run it without gdb it crashes with a segmentation fault at clone() but it works fine if I use gdb. Why?

Do you think this is a good practice or will I run into troubles sooner or later?
And is there a better method to achieve this?

Cheers,

Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack argument to `clone` is a simple `void*`. Also, the stack grows down on most architectures, so the stack pointer should point to the *end* of the allocated memory.

In any case, you shouldn't use `clone` directly unless you really need to avoid any dependencies on external libraries. Use the pthreads library instead. It provides a much easier (and safer) API.

Comment: Ok, but then I would have to create a mutex and lock it at the beginning of the for loop iteration and unlock it at the end?

If so, this I think this would hurt the performance.

Comment: I tried to use this, but the performace really breaks down strongly.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: @Manuel: In general, you would need to synchronize (e.g. using a mutex) with your current `clone`-based solution as well because the code is buggy as it is. In this particular example, you don't really need locking since you're just dumping an `int`. Your monitoring thread is sleeping every iteration, so you can actually miss some integers (the code doesn't necessarily print 1, 2, 3, 4 - it could print 1, 3, 4 as well).

Comment: I know. And it should not print 1, 2, 3...
I just want to keep track if there is process.

The actual question is: if I read and write in one thread, is it safe to _only_ read in another thread?

Answer (score 0):

On intel processors, the `child_stack` argument should point to the top of the stack, not to the bottom.

Anyway, I think using `clone` is not a good idea. There are about three ways of calling `clone`, depending on architercture, all poorly documented. I'd suggest using the pthreads library (or, since we are in C++, Boost.Threads).